# IllegalAccessError while working on inheritance - Why?

Tags: java, inheritance

I found [this JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021581) and want to understand why it happens.

The scenario (taken from [the bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021581)) is very simple: a `class` declaring a `private` method, and an `interface` declaring a `public` method with the same signature. It compiles without error.

However, when I run this code I am getting `IllegalAccessError`

```
interface I {
    public void m();
}

class A {
    private void m() {
        System.out.println("Inside Class A");
    }

}

abstract class B extends A implements I {
}

class C extends B {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("Inside Class C");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new C();
        b.m();
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why this error is there as **my code is compiling fine**.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:  
tried to access method A.m()V from class Test
    at Test.main(Test.java:25)
```

Comment: Interestingly if you declare the type of the `b` variable as `I` instead of `B`, it works.

Comment: @JonSkeet-- Sir I also change m() to public and it worked too.

Comment: @LoneWolf when you stated `I also change m() to public`, you meant in `class A` and same behaviour (compile is OK but exception is raised on run)? I copy-pasted your code (Java 1.8.0_144). Strangely, when `m()` is private in `A`, I have the same behaviour but if `m()` is public in `A`, everything is fine (compile and run OK)

Comment: @LoneWolf it will work when you change method `m()` to `public` in Type `A` as it will just override the methods and will print `"Inside class C"`

Comment: @LoneWolf If you change the return type of method `m()` in Type `A` also, it will work. Coz, it will not hide the method `m()` from interface `I`.

Comment: Eclipse even highlights `A.m()` warning that it is never accessed locally (and thus not at all, as it is private).

Comment: It'll also run fine if `B b` is changed to `C b`.

Comment: no matter how I look at this, I see a bug :|

Comment: [The bug report scraper strikes again.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6684387)

Comment: @shmosel that's since java-6, impressive find. thank u

Comment: @Eugene OP is a serial plagiarizer. Most of his posts follow this pattern.

Comment: @shmosel-- Just sharing knowledge dude, by hook or by crook... :)

Comment: @Hulk- No, I really don't know that was bug, i found it on one of the technical blogs which says -Java's pitfall's , i did not get any satisfactory answer there so I shared it here.

Comment: This question seems to contain verbatim copies of text and example code from [JDK-8021581 Private class methods interfere with invocations of interface methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021581)
`[...] a very simple scenario. Just a class declaring a private method, and an interface declaring a public method with the same signature. It compiles without error.` Please make sure you properly mark your quotes for what they are!

Answer (score 8):

It compiles as everything seems fine.

However `b.m()` is translated as searching the signature `m()`, in `B`, evidently first in `A` and (intended) later in the interfaces. In `A` a private `m()` is found and ***bang***.

*Inconsistent language behaviour, and theoretically avoidable by the compiler.*

---

***Reworded***

During compilation the public interface method is found - fine. During runtime the (modifierless) signature is found in A where the method is private, never reaching the signature in the interface where the method is public.

---

***[FYI] Disassembly with javap***

```
invokevirtual method .../.../B.m:()V
```

Of course on a `C` object.

Comment: what you are essentially saying is that modifiers are not looked at before even trying to invoke the method? if so, this is a bug, a very interesting one

Comment: Do you think this behavior is legal or unspecified?

Comment: @Hulk absolutely not legal IMO, you *might* now even know there is such a private method

Comment: @Eugene reworded. Signatures are name + parameter types; but at run-time the modifier is checked (IllegalAccess).

Comment: @Hulk IMHO the compiler should reject compiling B as A and I stand in conflict. Or the language design should allow introducing a public method with the same signature as a private method, and make that private method not part of the virtual method lookup.

Comment: @JoopEggen *for the VM* signatures are name + parameter *+ return type*, just a side note; otherwise excellent IMHO comment...

Comment: @JoopEggen But that was my understanding so far - for the JLS private methods are not part of virtual method lookups as they cannot be inherited.

Comment: For the Java compiler, `C.m()` is the only possible implementation, without any ambiguity whatsoever.

Comment: When I said the same thing everyone downvoted my answer :(

Comment: @Hulk that was my understanding too (about the virtual method lookup), but evidently for a `b.m()` the compiler generates something fishy.

Comment: @Sridhar and you even cited... Still keep at it, and I also had to rephrase my answer. Certainly will get some downvote too.

Comment: Reference for the compile-time side, specified in Chapter 15.12 Method Invocation Expressions: [JLS 15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1): "If the form is TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier, then the type to search is the type denoted by TypeName." and [15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) : "[...] to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable [...]"

Comment: I did a disassembly, and was not surprised to see an invokevirtual (=call) to a B method signature. And at runtime B.class is inspected, then first A, bang, and no longer virtual method in I/C.

Comment: @Hulk ... and private not being "accessible" - and of course I not uplifting private to public. I wonder how other compilers behave, IBM/eclipse J9 or pre-Java 8.

Comment: @JoopEggen javac-9 compiles/runs it in the same way

Comment: @Eugene thanks, but that is java version 9, isn't it, not J9 the IBM compiler? Both ways it adds a bit more to the "insights."

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and currently tracked here:

[JDK-8021581
Private class methods interfere with invocations of interface methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021581)

This ticket does contain a detailed analysis of the issue, discussion of compatibility concerns and risks of proposed solutions and is still open.

Older discussions of the topic can be found here:

[JDK-6684387 IllegalAccessError for code passed by compiler](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6684387)
(that one was linked by [shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444657/illegalaccesserror-while-working-on-inheritance-why/46447915?noredirect=1#comment79862800_46444657) - thanks for that)

[JDK-6691741
JLS membership algorithm is too strong for JVMS method resolution](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6691741)

---

Comment: @LoneWolf My intention for turning it into a community wiki was to make it easier to keep it up to date (for example when the issue is resolved). Everybody is invited to edit, even substantial edits are welcome if/when new information is available. It also means I won't get any reputation from this answer, which I don't want because it wasn't me who dug out the ticket.

Comment: You can still accept it if it answers your question. And you should really add references to your sources of the parts you copy/pasted into your question.

Comment: @Hulk-- Thanks bro..(y)

Answer (score 1):

It compiles because class B is an abstract class that declares it implements interface I - it assumes that the implementation will have the required method.

The type of object b is declared as B at compile time. You can see that it is B and not C if you play a bit as in the examples below:

To make it simple with an example, if you have a new method in class c

```
class C extends B {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("C.m");
    }

    public void testFromC() {}
}
```

then trying to call this in your main, will not compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new C();
    b.testFromC(); // doesnt compile
}
```

While if you add a method in B, then it will be fine.

```
abstract class B extends A implements I {
    public void testFromB() { }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new C();
    b.testFromB(); // compiles
}
```

When it runs the program, treating as object of class B, it founds the implementation from A which is private. If you force b to be viewed as of type C by casting, it will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new C();
    ((C)b).testFromC();
}
```

Also, if you remove the private implementation of A for m it also would work without the casting.

```
class A {
    //private void m() {
    //System.out.println("A.m");
    //}
}
```

This works now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new C();
    b.m();
}
```

So as I understand it right now, it looks like at runtime first it checks for method m on B or its parent, and if it finds nothing, it goes to implementation of B which is of class C.

Comment: The question is why the runtime goes looking this up in the parent `A` when `B` declares it to be abstract - there cannot be a legal implementation in `A`.

Comment: Interestingly: if `B`explicitly declares `@Override public abstract void m();`, it works without exception.

Comment: Nice, having the @Override prevents checking for implementation in A and then it only can go to C that implements the abstract m

Comment: Why should the private method be invoked from a subclass. It is a bug for sure.

Comment: The point is on how the method to be called is resolved. The exception is thrown precisely because the method is private and cannot be invoked. The resolution in this case seems problematic